# In android, How do i pass variable in picasso?

Tags: android, picasso, universal-image-loader, android-glide

I have loaded image in android with picasso before, but this time not able to show. I am sending variable value using bundle from one activity to other , i am able to fetch it in other activity, i can see it in my logcat, but picasso doesnt load it. Heres how i am trying:

```
 Picasso.with(UserAreaActivity.this).load(pic).into(im);
```

Here pic is a string variable with which consists of the url, and i checked in logcat info whether pic is getting the url from another activity, it shows it has url , but then why picasso doesnt display it?

heres my xml code of imageview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.letslogin.UserAreaActivity"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:weightSum="1">
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="0.41" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you do a findViewById when you assigned im?  Are there errors in the logcat?  You haven't provided enough code to see what the problem is.

Comment: yes mate i obviously did findviewbyid, i am able to see image now, the problem was image was tooo big to load , so i added .resize(100,100) and . centercrop() to the picasso code. Now its working.